# Comparing Mac's and Unix manuals?

Tags: macos, unix, diff, manpage

How can I list differences between Mac's and Unix manuals?

For example, between the following commands

```
uniq
guniq
```

I tried the following unsuccessfully

```
diff (man uniq) (man guniq)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should be

```
diff <(man uniq) <(man guniq)
```

To answer saua's question from the comments:

Bash turns `<(...)` into a named pipe, which the diff program sees as a file.  So as far as diff knows, it's comparing two files.

Comment: Woah! How does that work? How does diff know which lines come from which command?

Comment: Oh, some experimentation already showed me: "echo <(man uniq)" is quite revealing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
man uniq > uniq.man
man guniq > guniq.man
diff uniq.man guniq.man
```