# Encoding Problem in Vimdiff?

Tags: encoding, vimdiff

How can you solve the following encoding problem?
http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/175564/encoding.png

It is rather hard to compare the manuals.

Comment: This is releated to "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621789/comparing-macs-and-unix-manuals", by the way.

Comment: The problem is that "man" is outputting all the formatting to make bold and underlines and that sort of thing.

Comment: So it seems that the best way is to use sdiff without Vim. I just would like to have colors to show the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
vim -d <(man uniq |col -b) <(man guniq |col -b)
```